# How Can I Display MP3 ID3 Tags in Mac OS X's Finder?

Tags: macos, mp3, finder

Is there any way to get Finder to show mp3 fields? (artist, title, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same problem then i started using [AudioFinder](http://www.icedaudio.com/)

> AudioFinder invented the genre of sound browsers, by being the first dedicated sound browser on any platform. With a long history of inovation, AudioFinder has consistently broke new ground and with free updates you can expect to always get more value added.

Comment: er... what does this have to do with being able to see mp3 fields in Finder?

Comment: If you click on the link, it actually shows integration with OS X Finder

Comment: As of May 2018, the AudioFinder website does not appear to have any content demonstrating the OS X Finder integration. I installed it, and it's unclear how it enhances the finder

Answer (score 0):

After struggling with this for years, I finally came up with a hack that works to my satisfaction. Unfortunately, it only gives you access to one tag. In my case the desired meta is "bitrate".

To begin, I created a script with the [eyeD3](https://eyed3.readthedocs.io/) Python library that grabs an mp3's bitrate, writes it to the "comment" tag and returns it:

```
import eyed3
import sys

filename = sys.argv[1]

from eyed3 import mp3
f = mp3.Mp3AudioFile(filename)

bitrate = f.info.bit_rate[1]
str_bitrate = str(bitrate).encode("utf-8").decode("utf-8")
f.tag.comments.set(str_bitrate)

f.tag.save()
exit(str_bitrate)
```

Next, I created a bash script that takes a folder, runs the python script on it, and sets the Mac OS "comment" field to the bitrate:

```
for f in "$1"*.mp3;
do
    echo "$f";
    updated=$(python bitrate.py "$f" 2>&1);

    comment=$(mdls -r -nullMarker "" -n kMDItemFinderComment "$f")

    printf "%s ( comment ): %s\n" "${1##*/}" "$comment"

    /usr/bin/osascript -e "set filepath to POSIX file \"$f\"" \
    -e "set the_File to filepath as alias" \
    -e "tell application \"Finder\" to set the comment of the_File to \"$updated\""

done
```

Finally, I created an Automator script that takes a folder as its input and passes it to the bash script:
[image]

This gives you a context menu item which, when clicked,
[image]

and the comment column is enabled,
[image]

Gives you a finder column with your meta value in it:
[image]

Comment: When I upgraded to Catalina this solution broke. I posted the solution here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/388555/83869